# PHP Check if output from MySql is a Digit or String

Tags: php

In php, how do I check if a variable is a string or digit?

I'm doing a `count()` using mysql, and wanted to know if the output is a string or a digit.

I know about is_numeric() and other functions in php, but is there something, if supplied a value will echo if the value is a digit or string?

Comment: Won't the output of `Count()` always be a digit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try with [`gettype`](http://php.net/gettype) function.

```
gettype('foo'); // string
gettype(1.23);  // double
gettype(155);   // integer
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you use a framework or a data abstraction layer, and this treat the output of the database, customarily data type is lost along the way and everything becomes string.
is_numeric is the most indicated in this cases!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Use:

```
echo $gettype($YourValueFromDB);
```

and in your situation it **will** output:

```
string
```

OR

```
if(is_int($YourValueFromDB))
{
    echo 'we have an integer type!';
}
elseif(is_string($YourValueFromDB))
{
    echo 'we have a string type!';
}
else
{
    echo 'Not sure: '.gettype($YourValueFromDB);
}
```

**Long answer:**

MySQL produces a number value with this query:

```
select count(*) as total from table
// can range from 0 - infinity (or exhausted memory limit, whichever comes first)
// for this post, pretend this count() returns a 9
```

When this data is passed back to PHP it is automatically converted into a string due to PHP's extremely relaxed type-casting.

Running this:

```
var_dump($row);
```

would produce something like this:

```
array
    'total' => string '9' (length=1)
```

indicating that you are working with a literal string but it's value is a number so things like `if($row['total'] > 1){ }` would go inside the curly braces without a problem.